# Centralizer of a Matrix over a Finite Field

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbb F$ be a finite field. Denote by $M_n(\mathbb F)$ the set of matrices of order $n$ over $\mathbb F$. For a matrix $A\in M_n(\mathbb F)$ what is the cardinality of 
$C_{ M_n(\mathbb F)}(A)$, the centralizer of $A$ in  $M_n(\mathbb F)$? There are papers about it?

Comment: One messy case is when $A$ is unipotent. A calculation of the centralizer in some of those cases is done in a paper of P. Hall and G. Higman (Proc LMS, 1956)

Comment: Now asked also on MathOverflow: [Centralizer of a Matrix over a Finite Field](https://mathoverflow.net/q/105040).